# How to center the ad at the bottom center of the screen (libgdx + AdMob)

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, libgdx

I am using libgdx and AdMob.   I am having trouble getting the ad to center in the bottom of the screen.   In the current setup, I have it in the bottom left corner of the screen, but it will not center.

Code in my MainActivity

```
 // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was being dumb.   The code I was using was already correct, but I needed to remove the align left.  I guess calling left and then center the call afterward didn't stick.

```
// Add the AdMob view
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
//adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

layout.addView(adView, adParams);
```

This works.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted -- this post helped me!

Answer (score 0):

for libgdx paste this code in ur android class in onCreate()

layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adMObid );

```
View gameView=initializeForView(new TalkingFriendApp(this), cfg);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
adParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_CENTER);

adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

layout.addView(gameView, adParams);
layout.addView(adView, adParams1);

setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: This doesn't compile.  RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_CENTER is not a real thing.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html  

It seems that you put your adview on the top left.  I can move it from corner to corner.

Comment: i have edited the answer and make sure ur android version is 3.2 or higher